# warning when using createEx for window creation in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am getting waring 
**"Warning: Window creation failed: GetLastError returns 0x00000579"**
when using below code

```
CWnd* m_pWndStatic = new CWnd;
m_pWndStatic->CreateEx(0, _T("STATIC"),
                      _T("Hi"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP,
                      CRect(0, 0, 20, 20), this, 1234);
```

It works fine if i call it without PopUp i.e. WS_POPUP. I am using VS2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_INVALID_MENU_HANDLE
//
// MessageText:
//
// Invalid menu handle.
//
#define ERROR_INVALID_MENU_HANDLE        1401L
```

Which puts you on the wrong track, the real problem is that you can't create a *child window* that's also a popup window.  Only top level windows can be popups.  The diagnostic is generated because for a popup window, it interprets the "1234" argument you pass as a menu handle instead of a child window ID.

Remove the WS_POPUP style flag.